# Make all images sepia svg code not working?

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

So, I wanted to make all images with sepia effect, however code I use for grayscale in SVG, when changed to sepia doesn't work...

This is grayscale: `a img {
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); }`

And this is sepia that doesn't work: `img {
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id="sepia"><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.393 0.769 0.189 0 0 0.349 0.686 0.168 0 0 0.272 0.534 0.131 0 0 0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#sepia"); }`

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with sepia code?

And since I'm asking is there a way to make images both sepia and grayscale and play with opacities like with web-kit where I can make it `-webkit-filter: grayscale(1) sepia (0.2);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the double quotes in [id="sepia"]. Also, your values for sepia seem a bit off. This is a better place to start for sepia:

```
       "0.30 0.30 0.30 0 0
        0.25 0.25 0.25 0 0
        0.20 0.20 0.20 0 0
        0.00 0.00 0.00 1 0"
```

On your other question, you can use `<animate>` to animate between color matrix values, but svg animation doesn't work on IE (even IE10), so you'll have to script something that makes sense. (Update - you can try the FakeSMIL javascript library for IE - it can handle most SMIL.)